# How to remove H2 tag from some blocks

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-zen

I would like to remove the H2 tag from search and some other blocks (not from all of them by block.tpl.php). I use sub theme of Zen. Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: please read [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) and [FAQs](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to blocks configuration page -> edit block -> enter `<none>` as a title.
This is the CMS way and this is how you should do it.

Comment: Thank you Merijn!
It works fine but I don't know why it doesn't work only for the Search form block!? Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: The problem is solved. I have removed the h2 tag from the search module.

Answer (score 2):

It's a vague question so the answer will be equally vague...

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['block']->info == 'foo') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__no_title';
  }
}
```

Then add a block--no-title.tpl.php file to your theme, copy the markup from block.tpl.php, and remove the `<h2>`. Clear Drupal's theme registry cache and you're done.

Comment: Ok. I have created the file block--no-title.tpl.php without <h2> but I don't know where to place the code - I have tried in template.php of my sub theme (also in the Zen theme) but there is the error "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$info in MYTHEME_preprocess_block()" with the name of my theme. Can you please enplane in details what I have to do because I am not so experienced in Drupal and php.

Comment: Sorry no, if you don't know PHP or Drupal I can't help you

Answer (score 1):

Clive has already answered the question which is, IMO, correct - but as you are saying you are not very experienced with PHP, let me suggest something that does not involve coding - but keep in mind: Learning Drupal and PHP is easy and a fun if you have plenty of time to read docs and testing.

From "remove h2", I'm assuming you mean to remove the h2 tag with class `title`. 
In the block's configuration page, enter `<none>` as the title of the block - your block will not contain the title (and its `h2` tag).

This is a per-block setting.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to remove the H2 tag for SEO reasons, I'd like to suggest a trick to take advantage of the "Search form" string.Find for "Search form" Label from your language file (default english)and replace it with "Your SEO Text".